# using boolan in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

```
for item in query_results:
    num +=1
    print num
```

this will give you 1, 2, 3, 4 etc

I then tried doing this in django templates doing the following

```
{% for item in query_results %}
<tr>
<td>{{ item.user }}</td>
<td>{{ num|add:"1" }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

But this only returns 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 etc. This says to me that the 1 isn't being saved to num each cycle. IS this then not a capability of django templates, or am i just doing it wrong.

Comment: where is the boolean that you mention in the title?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [forloop.counter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs) instead.

```
{% for item in query_results %}
<tr>
<td>{{ item.user }}</td>
<td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `add` filter just adds the argument to the value, but doesn't modify it. That's why you're getting always `1` as result.

More about it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#add